# Why does On Error Goto Label not work after it succesfully bypassed error first time?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I encountered an issue in my VBA code.

```
Option Explicit
Dim X As Integer
Dim Rng As String
 
 
Sub runtime91()
Sheet1.Select               'Select the first sheet
        
For X = 1 To 43             'Setting the loop
Rng = Sheets("Reference").Cells(153 + X, 8).Value   'assigning variable for cells containing the last registration dates
If Rng = "0" Or Rng = "" Then           'Logical testing for periods with the last registration dates
Else
    On Error GoTo continue
    Cells.Find(What:=Rng, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
            xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False).Select       'Find the last registration dates based on reference datas
    If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = ActiveCell  'Write the last registration dates
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Column = 9 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveCell  'Write the last registration dates
    End If
End If
continue:
Next
 
End Sub
```

This code is checking from cell H154 to cell H196 in the reference tab. These cells contain date as string. If the current cell is empty or equals to 0 then go to next iteration. If the cell contains date string, then it will try to find the corresponding date in the Sheet1 tab.

The issue is: it gave runtime error 91 at the second attempt of not finding the date in Sheet1 tab. The On Error Goto continue bypassed the first attempt of not finding the date - it went straight to the next iteration.

I am confused as the `On Error Goto continue` only bypassed error one time as I expect it would bypass the error until the loop ends.

Below is the dropbox link to the worksheet if you need it.

```
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/cc83cwku0d8kk7le2j7yi/Runtime-error-91.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=64yovaxo87wlosjgc235j6dlj
```

Any sugesstions on this matter are appreciated.

Comment: Your issue is because you don't clear the first error so the second error sort of has nowhere to go since an error already exists. It's something along those lines. Your best method is to add a `Resume` to clear it. Under your `continue:` line add this line: `On Error Resume Next`. I can't remember entirely but that should work. If not, there are a couple other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the error handler between each error:

```
Option Explicit

Sub errtest()
    Dim A As Integer

    On Error GoTo Continue
    A = 1 / 0                 'Will cause an error that is handled here
Continue:
    MsgBox "Took care of error"
    On Error GoTo -1        'Reset error handling
    On Error GoTo Continue2 'Set error handling
    A = 1 / 0
Continue2:
    MsgBox "Took care of error again"
    A = 1 / 0
    MsgBox "Took care of error yet another time" 'Will never be executed
End Sub
```

Read more here:
https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling

Answer (score 2):

Don't use error handling when you can just check the return value.

```
Dim foundCell As Range

Set foundCell = Cells.Find(What:=Rng, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If foundCell Is Nothing Then
    ' value not found

elseIf foundCell.Column = 1 Then
    foundCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = foundCell.Value  'Write the last registration dates

ElseIf foundCell.Column = 9 Then
    foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = foundCell.Value  'Write the last registration dates

end if
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [per this MS documentation on the `On Error` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement);

> If an error occurs while an error handler is active (between the occurrence of the error and a Resume, Exit Sub, Exit Function, or Exit Property statement), the current procedure's error handler can't handle the error.

As you are not handling the error in any way, you might find using `On Error Resume Next` instead such as:

```
On Error Resume Next
'Do some loops and code here
'More code doing things
'Code doing things has finished now, onto the next task
On Error GoTo -1     'This resets the error handling
```

**NOTE:** this method will ignore ALL errors, not just expected ones so be cautious for unexpected results.

The best method would be to, if you expect the errors, modify your code to check for criteria that will cause the error and prevent an error being thrown all together.